# Given a vector a=[1,2, 3.2, 4, 5] and an element x=3 In vector a, how to find the exact entry which is bigger than x?

Tags: matlab

Given a vector a=[1,2, 3.2, 4, 5] and an element x=3
In vector a, how to find the exact entry which is bigger than x?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "exact" entry. This will give you indices of *all* the values greater than `x`:

```
indices = find(a > x);
```

Assuming `a` is already sorted, this will give you the index of the first one (i.e. the smallest value greater than `x`):

```
index = find(a > x,1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compute these positions for multiple values of `x`, you will be better off using `histc` instead of looping through all values of `x`, as in terms of complexity `histc` will be `O(n*log(n))`, while the loop approach will be `O(n^2)`:

```
[~,I] = histc(x, [-Inf; a(:); Inf]);
I(x==inf) = numel(a)+1;
```

This will work for sorted `a` and arbitrary `x`. As an example:

```
a = 1:10;
x = [5.5, 0.1, 2.3];
```

Will yield:

```
I = [6     1     3]
```