# MATLAB - how do I find the first index where value is greater than threshold

Tags: matlab, find

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Given a vector a=[1,2, 3.2, 4, 5] and an element x=3 In vector a, how to find the exact entry which is bigger than x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593717/given-a-vector-a-1-2-3-2-4-5-and-an-element-x-3-in-vector-a-how-to-find-the)

Let's say a[] is a sorted vector. How do I find the first(smallest) index ix such that a(ix) > threshold?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
ix = find(a>threshold,1);
```

Pretty sure this will work

Comment: No, you don't. From Matlab documentation: `I = FIND(X,K,'first') is the same as I = FIND(X,K).` You only need to indicate `'last'` if you want it the other way around.

Comment: both phonon and oli will work.

Comment: oh duh. Of course. I didn't see the `,1`. Sorry about that :)

Comment: @Phonon: Yeah, `first` is unnecessary.  But I usually include it to make it explicitly clear what my intention is.

Comment: I agree. There's no harm in being rigorous in you function calls = )

Answer (score 15):

```
ix = find(a > threshold, 1, 'first');
```

Answer (score 5):

for the heck of it, 
if and only if a is sorted, you can do it like this:

```
ix = sum(a<=threshold)+1;
```

Comment: Not exactly direct and elegant, but very innovative; therefore +1 = )