# Extracting parts of varying length from time series

Tags: matlab, time, time-series

I have a long time series file (recorded in milliseconds) and I need to extract from it parts of varying lengths (based on the values from a different array/file).

The time series file (*data2.txt*) was exported from the EEGLab toolbox because I need to try a custom analysis. It has two columns (1st: time in ms, 2nd: values from EEG recordings) - see below. 
I have stored timing (beginning and end) of the epochs in a different file (*epochs.txt*: 1st column - start, 2nd - end) in the same format as *data2.txt*.

My file (*data2.txt*) looks in the following way:

```
0.0000  -126.2498
1.9531  -91.8123
3.9063  -130.7185
5.8594  -67.2498
7.8125  -77.6560
9.7656  -83.0623
11.7188 -74.0310
13.6719 -110.4685
15.6250 -130.4373
17.5781 -143.4060
19.5313 -155.7498
```

I need to extract the values from parts of the time series (timing is saved in the external file - *epochs.txt*) and save them to another file.

I have stored timing (beginning and end) of the epochs in a different file (*epochs.txt*: 1st column - start, 2nd - end). The values in *epochs.txt* might not always be the same as in *data2.txt*, e.g.:
(can they be interpolated?)

```
2.391391554 5.381023353
6.129570888 7.39010542
10.65197062 12.96686866
14.47654996 17.31346859
17.84561721 18.88671436
22.3857703  23.25648467
```

The file looks fine when loaded and plotted:

```
EEG_data = importdata('C:\Users\Me\Desktop\data2.txt');
figure
plot(EEG_data(:,1), EEG_data(:,2));
```

I guess Matlab is treating my file as a 2-by-N matrix and not as a time series but I'm not sure how to change it. I tried transforming *EEG_data* to a time series and extracting the corresponding values but I failed miserably.

I'd like to get the output (*output.txt*) that would have two columns (1st: time, 2nd: EEG values), a possible output below is based on the first row of *epochs.txt* (1st column of *output.txt*) and the second column is guesstimated. 
I'm not sure what would be the best way to get the values in between.

```
2.391391554 -90.381023353
.
.
.
5.381023353 -75.96686866
```

Any ideas how to tackle this problem?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Everything seems fine. What exactly are you failing to do?

Comment: I need to extract the values from the second column of *data2.txt* (the first column is timing) based on the timing (start/end) in *epochs.txt*. I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @Memming the rows of `epochs2.txt` are start and end times that correspond to the first column of `data2.txt`, which should then be used to select values of the second column of `data2.txt`. The main issue seems to be that the times do not exactly match, so the values need to be interpolated.

Comment: Is the question how to convert non-uniformly sampled time series to another non-uniform grid of times? I suggest you update the title of the question.

Comment: I think if your signal is band-limited (highest frequency component is known), and your non-uniform sampling is above a generalized Nyquist limit, you can resample the signal on a uniform grid by low-pass filtering. Is this what you wanted to know?

Comment: This particular file was recorded at 512 Hz, but eventually I will run the analysis on another that was sampled at 16kHz. My question was how to extract parts of the given time series, whether it is possible in the current form (and how to do it), and if not then what should be done.

Comment: @epo3 in your output, how do you want to select readings between each start and end time? Should these also be interpolated to maintain some kind of equal time spacing, or taken directly from the input? If they are interpolated, how should the program decide how many samples should be taken?

Comment: Probably the easiest way would be to select the readings directly from the input. If that works, then it should be good enough without interpolation. My time windows should be around 170 ms long so I will have enough values to load there. If that won't work, then I'll worry about interpolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, here is some code to get you started. I have used the following data to avoid handling empty slices where `start_index == end_index`. You may want to add some code to check for this and other problematic cases.

epochs.txt

```
2.391391554 9.381023353
11.65197062 18.96686866
```

data2.txt

```
0.0000  -126.2498
1.9531  -91.8123
3.9063  -130.7185
5.8594  -67.2498
7.8125  -77.6560
9.7656  -83.0623
11.7188 -74.0310
13.6719 -110.4685
15.6250 -130.4373
17.5781 -143.4060
19.5313 -155.7498
```

Code

```
EEG_data = importdata('data2.txt');
epochs = importdata('epochs.txt');

output = zeros(0, 2);
for i = 1:size(epochs, 1)
    % extract an epoch from the EEG data
    start_time = epochs(i, 1);
    end_time = epochs(i, 2);

    % find corresponding indices
    % http://stackoverflow.com/q/3593717/553404
    start_index = find(EEG_data(:, 1) > start_time, 1);
    end_index = find(EEG_data(:, 1) > end_time, 1) - 1;

    % slice the required data for the epoch
    epoch_data = EEG_data(start_index:end_index, :);

    % append to output
    output = [output; epoch_data];
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm. I've added save(['epoch',num2str(i)],'epoch_data');  to save every epoch in a separate file (I will have to normalize them).